# JAVA long comparison seemingly inaccurate

Tags: java, equality

Having an issue where I need to compare to long values and check for equality. My relevant code is listed below:

```
for(int i = 0; i <=results.size()-1; i++) {
        if(results.get(i).get(0).getTime() == results.get(i).get(results.get(i).size()-1).getTime()){
            continue;
        }
}
```

When setting a breakpoint,

```
results.get(i).get(0).getTime()     has value: 1329286731000
results.get(i).get(results.get(i).size()-1).getTime()     has value: 1329286731000
```

however the comparison is returning false. Any ideas here?

Note: results is a List> and the LocationEvent class can be found below:

```
public class LocationEvent implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * The unique identifier for this event
 */
private Integer id;

/**
 * The date and time that this location event was recorded in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
 */
private Long time;

/**
 * The latitude at which the event occurred
 */
private Double latitude;

/**
 * * The longitude at which the event occurred
 */
private Double longitude;

/**
 * The speed the resource was traveling at the time of the event in MPH
 */
private Double speed;

/**
 * The direction the resource was traveling at the time of the event (i.e. N, S, NW, SE, etc).
 */
private String direction;

/**
 * The altitude at which the event occurred in feet above sea level
 */
private Double altitude;

/**
 * The closest known address to the location.
 */
private String nearestAddress;

/**
 * Any available comment describing this location event
 */
private String comment;

/**
 * The source of this event (i.e. GeoProductSolutions, GpsInsight, Multispeak, WirelessMatrix, WiSys, NiscMobile,
 * AppSuite-iOS, AppSuite-Android)
 */
private String source;

/**
 * The device to which this event is associated
 */
private LocationDeviceSummary device;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Double getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(Double speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

public String getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public void setDirection(String direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
}

public Double getAltitude() {
    return altitude;
}

public void setAltitude(Double altitude) {
    this.altitude = altitude;
}

public String getNearestAddress() {
    return nearestAddress;
}

public void setNearestAddress(String nearestAddress) {
    this.nearestAddress = nearestAddress;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public LocationDeviceSummary getDevice() {
    return device;
}

public void setDevice(LocationDeviceSummary device) {
    this.device = device;
}
}
```

Comment: what are types of variables?

Comment: What is `results`? What is `getTime`? We'll need more information about what exactly is going on in your code before we can help.

Comment: Does this matter? Both values I am checking for equality are longs? results is a list of list of custom objects and getTime() returns a long that is time in milliseconds

Comment: Provide full code.What is `results`, what it contains , data type etc

Answer (score 3):

If your results are `Long`s rather than `long`s, the `==` operator may return `false` no matter the equality of the values.

You may want to use `equals` or invoke `longValue()` with `==` for comparison.

**Note**

Integer values are cached if in range `Byte.MIN_VALUE <= x <- Byte.MAX_VALUE`, hence a `==` comparison within that range would return `true`.

Comment: Ah thank you very much... must've been having a moment to not think of using .equals()

Comment: You're welcome. You could use `==` reliably if they were primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Check this two examples:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long x=1329286731000l;
        Long y=1329286731000l;
        System.out.println(y==x);
    }
}
```

It returns **false** because theyare equals but they are different objects:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x=1329286731000l;
        long y=1329286731000l;
        System.out.println(y==x);
    }
}
```

It returns true because It compares the value.

Your `get(0).getTime()` returns a Long so you have to use equals in the fowllowing way:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long x=1329286731000l;
        Long y=1329286731000l;
        System.out.println(y.equals(x));
    }
}
```